# Radio schedule php

Tags: php

I am making a radio scheduler. It should show which program is on now.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "Dennis", "***") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("daletnew") or die(mysql_error());
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$day = date('l');
$hour = date('H');


$query = "SELECT time_end FROM shows WHERE day='$day' AND time_start='$hour'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM shows WHERE day='$day' AND time_start='$hour'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) { 

echo '<div id="onair_info" style="position: relative; top: 40px;">';
echo '<br />';
echo '<div class="info_time_time" style="position: relative; left: 4px; color: #2980b9; font-size: 18px; font-family: Roboto; font-weight:300; top: -10px; ">';
echo "FavoriteFM Music";
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

} else {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $show_name = $row['show_name'];
     $DJ = $row['DJ'];
      $time_start = $row['time_start'];
      $time_stop = $row['time_stop'];

      $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DJ WHERE DJ='$DJ'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
 { 
$image_url = $info1['image_url'];
}

echo '<div id="circle" style="position: relative; top: 40px; left: 175px; width:50px;height:50px; border-color:#00aeff; border-radius:50px; line-height:100px;text-align:center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(' . $image_url . ');"></div>';      
echo '<div id="onair_info" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">';
echo '<div class="info_time_LIVE" style="position: relative; color: #2980b9; font-size: 12px; font-family: Roboto;top: -12px;left: 20px;">';
echo 'LIVE </div>';
echo '<div class="info_time_time" style="position: relative; left: 60px; color: #2980b9; font-size: 12px; font-family: Roboto;top: -26px;">';
echo $time_start;
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="arrow_to_right" style="position: relative; width:15px; top: -40px;left: 80px;height:15px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(\'http://test.favoritefm.com/wp-content/themes/FavoriteFM/img/arrow_to_right.png\')"></div>';
echo '<div class="info_time_time" style="position: relative; left: 100px; color: #2980b9; font-size: 12px; font-family: Roboto;top: -55px;">';
echo $time_stop;
echo '</div>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<div class="info_show" style="position: relative; top: -57px; left: 20px; color: #2980b9; font-size: 14px; font-family: Roboto;">';
echo '<div class="dj_name" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Roboto; font-weight: bold";>';
echo $DJ;
echo '</div>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<div class="show_name" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Roboto;position: relative;top: -15px">';
echo $show_name;
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
}

?>
```

Obviously, it shows shows that exactly last one hour. But now I have shows that start at 12 and end at 16. I don't know where to start or how to do it. How can I get the script to show a radio show between 12 and 16? I have the beginning and end time in the table als time_start and time_stop.

Comment: So, what? You're after the SQL to return all rows where the day is today and the current time is > the start time, the current time is < the end time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your second SQL line to this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Shows WHERE day='$day' AND time_start<=$hour AND time_stop>$hour";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

You can completely remove the first SQL query and keep all the other code the same. It uses SQL comparison operators that will return the radio show if the current hour is between the start and end hours. Using your example (12-16 hours), 12:15 and 15:50 would return the show, but 11:55 and 16:05 would not.

**Edit:** Please ensure that time_start and time_stop are SQL Int type, and that $hour is an Int. The comparison operators can't compare strings.

Comment: Dennis, please clarify what you mean by "empty rows": do you mean it's not returning anything? Or more results than it should?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Even if I use this query by hand, it shows '0 rows'.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Only if I change the query to 


SELECT * 
FROM shows
WHERE DAY =  'Monday'
AND time_start >=11
AND time_stop <17


It works. If I change it to:


SELECT * 
FROM shows
WHERE DAY =  'Monday'
AND time_start >=13
AND time_stop <13


It doesn't work at all. 0 rows.

Comment: Wow I messed up! I reversed the comparison operators, try again please! And thanks for the helpful feedback!